# angularjs "hello world" directive + coffeescript not working

Tags: angularjs

assume I have my directives in

```
@directivesModule = angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
```

and in directive.coffee

```
directivesModule.directive 'showAuthorLogin', () ->
    restrict: 'E'
    template: '<div>Hello World</div>'
```

index.html:

```
<span showAuthorLogin></span>
```

why isn't anything showing?

Comment: what does the compiled javascript look like?

Comment: looks like this on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CXgw7/

Comment: ah your html needs to be <span show-author-login></span> . Angular converts it from camel case. I posted an example in my answer

Comment: thanks, didn't expect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`restrict: 'E'` means that the directive has to be an element. So you could change the directive to `restrict: 'A'` or you could change your html to: `<showAuthorLogin></showAuthorLogin>`

Here is an example of it working on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X6A7M/